# How to call Method with parameter in Activity?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I has been try many of code to call method but when i call method with parameter its send me an **error**. how i call this method with parameter from `BroadcastReceiver` or other `class`!?

**Update**

The **error** i can't  call method with `myMethod(View view);`

All this works perfectly. Now what I need is that I have to call a method with parameter of Activity this `Broadcast Receiver`, where I have created an custom `Toast`.

I have read many answers on stack-overflow.com and some website/youtube but cannot solve my problem maybe i don't understand clearly.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public void myMethod1(View view){
    //some code custom toast
    finish();

    }
    public void myMethod2(View view){
    //some code custom toast
    finish();
    }

    public void myMethod3(View view){
    //some code custom toast
    finish();
    }
}
```

I build this `activity` without display

and my Previous code work perfectly but i must create class on every custom `toast` here my previous code:

BroadcastReceiver

```
public class myBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED)) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    }
}
```

MyActivity

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lowbattery_toast, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.low_battery));
        Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 10);
        toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.setView(layout);
        toast.show();

        finish();
    }
}
```

I want to make my all custom `toast` on single activity by call method from broadcastReceiver.

any idea to solve my problem?

Comment: You can try to use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) to post some event with your parameters.

Comment: Any time you're asking about an error, you should copy and paste it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

you can put a flag value to intent,then in your activity class create a mehtod that  can show the different toast UI by flag value .